# Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to install Magento Edition 2.1.0  WAMP 3.0 Apache Version : 2.4.17  PHP Version : 7.0.0 on my local host, use   and i got

> Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements.

Does anyone have issue for this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to upgrade your PHP version :)

Comment: yes but when you use wamp it's a little difficult

Comment: There are lots of versions of PHP in WAMPServer if you just look for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ADDONS (Click/Download/Install) for all these PHP versions all available on SourceForge [or here on the download backup](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

```
PHP 5.3.29 x86
PHP 5.4.45 x86
PHP 5.5.30 x86
PHP 5.5.31 x86
PHP 5.5.32 x86
PHP 5.5.33 x86
PHP 5.5.34 x86
PHP 5.5.35 x86
PHP 5.5.36 x86
PHP 5.5.37 x86
PHP 5.5.38 x86
PHP 5.6.16 x86
PHP 5.6.17 x86
PHP 5.6.18 x86
PHP 5.6.19 x86
PHP 5.6.20 x86
PHP 5.6.21 x86
PHP 5.6.22 x86
PHP 5.6.23 x86
PHP 5.6.24 x86
PHP 5.6.25 x86
PHP 7.0.0 x86
PHP 7.0.1 x86
PHP 7.0.2 x86
PHP 7.0.3 x86
PHP 7.0.4 x86
PHP 7.0.5 x86
PHP 7.0.6 x86
PHP 7.0.7 x86
PHP 7.0.8 x86
PHP 7.0.9 x86
PHP 7.0.10 x86
```

--- 64 bit x64

```
PHP 5.6.17 x64
PHP 5.6.18 x64
PHP 5.6.19 x64
PHP 5.6.20 x64
PHP 5.6.21 x64
PHP 5.6.22 x64
PHP 5.6.23 x64
PHP 5.6.24 x64
PHP 5.6.25 x64
PHP 7.0.1 x64
PHP 7.0.2 x64
PHP 7.0.3 x64
PHP 7.0.4 x64
PHP 7.0.5 x64
PHP 7.0.6 x64
PHP 7.0.7 x64
PHP 7.0.8 x64
PHP 7.0.9 x64
PHP 7.0.10 x64
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Please confirm php version through terminal PHP -v. Then check echo phpinfo(); then check again, if both are the same and the latest version. it is fine. Else please enable the latest php version.

sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.x